# Actualizar una página entera a una hora en concreto usando javascript

Tags: javascript

He estado revisando  y quiero que una pagina entera se recargue a una hora concreta. Es decir a las 07:30:00 AM.

Que funcion de JavaScript puedo utilizar.

Yo he utilizado la siguiente :

```
    function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(11);
    then.setMinutes(50);
    then.setSeconds(00);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.reload(true);
    }, timeout);
}
```

Pero no hace nada.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: debes ejecutar  refreshAt(7,30,0); cuando cargues tu pagina, lo que hace es encontrar la diferencia desde la hora actual a la deseada, y poner un temporizador de esa diferencia encontrada

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución ha sido la siguiente:

```
window.onload = actualizarPagina();

        function actualizarPagina() {
            let actualizar = false;
            momentoActual = new Date();
            hora = momentoActual.getHours();
            minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes();
            segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds();

            str_segundo = new String (segundo);
            if (str_segundo.length == 1) {
                segundo = "0" + segundo;
            }
            str_minuto = new String (minuto);
            if (str_minuto.length == 1){
                minuto = "0" + minuto;
            }
            str_hora = new String (hora);
            if (str_hora.length == 1){
                hora = "0" + hora;
            }
            horaImprimible = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
            if(horaImprimible == "12:30:00") {
                actualizar = true;
            }
            setTimeout("actualizarPagina()",1000);
            if(actualizar == true) {//Comprueba que la hora es igual a la que quieres y actualiza
                location.reload();
            }
        }
```

Esto actualizó la página a las 12:30:00 para mi prueba ahí la puedes ir modificando para las pruebas necesarias que requieras para la comprobación de que dicha función realiza lo esperado.
Te dejo el html completo para que puedas comprobarlo antes de implementarlo a tu proyecto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Actualizar Página</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = actualizarPagina();

        function actualizarPagina() {
            let actualizar = false;
            momentoActual = new Date();
            hora = momentoActual.getHours();
            minuto = momentoActual.getMinutes();
            segundo = momentoActual.getSeconds();

            str_segundo = new String (segundo);
            if (str_segundo.length == 1) {
                segundo = "0" + segundo;
            }
            str_minuto = new String (minuto);
            if (str_minuto.length == 1){
                minuto = "0" + minuto;
            }
            str_hora = new String (hora);
            if (str_hora.length == 1){
                hora = "0" + hora;
            }
            horaImprimible = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
            if(horaImprimible == "12:30:00") {
                actualizar = true;
            }
            setTimeout("actualizarPagina()",1000);
            if(actualizar == true) {//Comprueba que la hora es igual a la que quieres y actualiza
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Esta página se actualizará a cierta hora: 12:30:00 por ejemplo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Posible solución** (he incluido un campo de entrada para poder cambiar la hora y probar el script)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
    * {
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -o-box-sizing:border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        margin: 5%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .form {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    input {
        display: block;
        margin: 12% auto;
        padding: 1rem;
        width: 132px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <p><strong>Problema:</strong> recargar la página cada día a una hora determinada</p>


    <div class="form">
        <input type="text" value="7:30:00" placeholder="hh:mm:ss" id="input">
        <input type="button" onclick="update()" value="Actualizar hora">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Datos entrantes

    let updateTime = '0:0:0';


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Script

    let arrUpdateTime = splitUpdateTime();

    function splitUpdateTime()
    {
        const arrUpdateTime = updateTime.split(':');
        for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
            arrUpdateTime[index] = parseInt(arrUpdateTime[index]);
        }

        return arrUpdateTime;
    }

    function checkToReload()
    {
        // console.log('checkToReload()'); // HACK: trace

        const date = new Date();
        if (date.getHours() === arrUpdateTime[0]
            && date.getMinutes() === arrUpdateTime[1]
            && date.getSeconds() === arrUpdateTime[2]
        ) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }

    setInterval('checkToReload()', 1000);
</script>

<script>
    function update()
    {
        updateTime = document.getElementById('input').value;
        arrUpdateTime = splitUpdateTime();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Desglosando el problema

**La página debe actualizarse a una hora concreta, en este caso 7:30 am**.

El script tiene varias partes:

1. Datos de arranque: por ejemplo una variable global con la hora de actualización.
2. La recarga de la página.
3. Un contador de tiempo.
4. El código de comprueba la hora actual con la de actualización.

Veamos con más detalle los puntos anteriores.

Guardo la hora de actualización (por defecto):

```
let updateTime = '7:30:00';
```

Voy a separar horas, minutos y segundos y convertirlos a números. Sólo necesito
hacerlo una vez, lo almaceno en otra global:

```
let arrUpdateTime = splitUpdateTime();

function splitUpdateTime()
{
    const arrUpdateTime = updateTime.split(':');
    for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        arrUpdateTime[index] = parseInt(arrUpdateTime[index]);
    }

    return arrUpdateTime;
}
```

Para recargar la página con javascript usamos:

```
location.reload();
```

*Esto recarga la ventana en la que se esta ejecutando el script. No se necesita llamar a `window` porque este ya es el contexto de ejecución en el navegador.*

Como hay que recargar la página a una hora concreta, *uso un reloj interno*, 
ejecutando `setTimeout()`, con un intervalo de 1 segundo. Se llama en cada ciclo 
a una función que comprobará la hora:

```
setInterval('checkToReload()', 1000);
```

La función que compara la hora actual con la de *recarga*:

```
function checkToReload()
{
    const date = new Date();

    if (date.getHours() === arrUpdateTime[0]
        && date.getMinutes() === arrUpdateTime[1]
        && date.getSeconds() === arrUpdateTime[2]
    ) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```